# React/Redux/React Router - Only call API when route is first visited or the filter is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Is there a way to only run `props.fetchTransactions()` under the following conditions:

1. When the route is first navigated to
2. If `props.filter` is changed

At the moment, it runs every time the route is navigated to because `<TransactionListContainer />` is unmounted and re-mounted by react router. This creates an unnecessary call to the API as it just re-fetches the exact same result set that is already in my Redux store.

The only way I can think of doing this is by lifting the `useEffect` hook up into the root `<App/>` so it's outside of the router, but i'm unsure if that's a good way to go because:

1. It will call the API when `<App/>` is loaded, even if the user is viewing a different route
2. `<App/>` will quickly become cluttered if I need to repeat this for other containers

```js
// App root
const App = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={ () =>  <TransactionListContainer /> } />
                ...other routes...
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}


// Container
const TransactionListContainer = (props) => {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        
        // This should only happen when the route is first visited or if props.filter has changed
        props.fetchTransactions(props.filter.fields, props.filter.pagination);
    
    },[props.filter]);

    // The transactions are passed to this container 
    // by redux: props.transactions. I haven't included 
    // any code that I believe isn't relevant 
    // to the question.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a flag variable indicating if the transaction data was cached previously (is available in redux store).

```
const TransactionListContainer = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!props.isCached){
          props.fetchTransactions(props.filter.fields, props.filter.pagination);
        }
    },[props.filter, props.isCached]);

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const isCached = state.transactions.length !== 0
  return { isCached }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TransactionListContainer)
```